# how to add opencv to a gui QT application?

Tags: qt, opencv

I created a new widget gui application in QT .
and in order to using opencv , I added *`INCLUDEPATH`* and `LIBS` to my projects as following :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testqt4
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include

LIBS += -LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib
-lopencv_world310d

HEADERS  += widget.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

and I included my desired opencv headers as following :

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
....
```

but when I builded the project I encountered with this error :

[image]

can anyone help me to fix this error ?
thank you .

Comment: The error is self descriptive. Check your paths. Check if `highgui/highgui.hpp` is present.

Comment: yes , this path exists but QT dont find this path . I don't know why this error happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using qt creator?

It will not update your makefile once you changed your `.pro` file.

Right click on the project folder in Projects view and click "Run qmake" should fix it.

Comment: Thank you .The problem solved , thank you very much indeed .